# How do I write a string into a file in C without writing (null)?

Tags: c, gcc, c99

This is what I have got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    
    unsigned short index;
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    index = rand(); 

    char * task = "";
    
    unsigned short i=0;
    
    for (; i < strlen(task); i+=task[i]) ;

    index = (index + i) % 999;

    FILE * file = fopen("file.txt", "a+");
    fprintf(file, "%03hu", index);
    
    for (unsigned short i=1; i<=argc; i++) {
        fprintf(file, " %s", argv[i]);
    }
    
    fwrite("\n", 1, 1, file); // was a solution to a similar question, still prints null characters
    // fprintf(file,"\n") and fputs(file,"\n") also print a null character into a file

    fclose(file);
}
```

When I read the file using cat I can see (null) at the end of lines. Example:

```
559 asd (null)
035 asd (null)
065 asd (null)
790 asd (null)
799 asd (null)
```

I have tried googling. Found one answer but it does not work.

Comment: `strlen(task)` will always be `0`, so `i` will always be `0`.

Comment: `i<=argc` should be `i<argc`.

Comment: You are misinterpreting `cat`'s output.  The `(null)` is not a representation of a null character appearing in the file.  It is a literal string that appears there, resulting from `printf` formatting `argv[argc]` (which is a null pointer by definition) as a string.

Comment: `argv[argc]` contains a null pointer. printing a null pointer with `%s` format is undefined behavior, but many implementations handle this by printing the string `(null)`.

Comment: Use `i < argc` as your loop condition instead of `i <= argc`.

Comment: As I said above.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - I don't believe fprintf will write a null char to the stream.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah fprintf doesnt write null characters

Comment: @JerryJeremiah *fprintf will always write a null character because it is formatted output* No, that's false.  `fprintf` should generally never write a null character.  (You may be thinking of `sprintf`).

Comment: I fixed the title of the question so it is not misleading anymore.  Apparently the OP's string does have a null character in it.

Comment: @DavidGrayson There is no "OP's string". The only strings he's writing are `argv[i]`.

Comment: @DavidGrayson, don't you mean *does not* have a null character in it?  There's no reason why the program presented would output one, and it indeed does not do so for me.

Comment: thak you all so much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing in your code outputs a null byte to the output file. The file contains the characters `(null)` at the end of the lines. The reason for this is the loop iterates up to and **including** `argc`, hence you use `printf` to output `argv[argc]`, which is a null pointer, and on your target system, `fprintf` outputs the string `"(null)"` in this case. Use a standard loop instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    fprintf(file, " %s", argv[i]);
}
fprintf(file, "\n");
```

No need to use `"a+"` mode in `fopen`, `"a"` will suffice as you never read from this file.

The line `for (; i < strlen(task); i+=task[i]) ;` is highly suspect, but since `task` points to an empty string, the loop exits immediately.

To output a portion of a string or one without a null terminator, you can use `fwrite(s, 1, length, file)` or `printf("%.*s", length, str)`.

Comment: thank you so much! i am stupid

Comment: @LevZagatov: everybody makes mistakes... the behavior of `fprintf` for a null pointer as actually undefined.  The output might have been different on a different system.  We just happen to know what it does and made the connection.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of problems with your code, but the problem that is causing the (nul) to appear in your output is the following:

```
for (unsigned short i=1; i<=argc; i++)
```

Specifically, `i<=argc` is wrong, your arguments range from `0` to `argc - 1`, so it should be `i < argc`.

However,`argv[argc]` is defined to be NULL, so you may "safely" access it without overrunning the array. But it will always be NULL. `fprintf()` is being kind to you and inserting the text `(null)` into the output stream, rather than causing a segfault.